# fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: macos, git, github

I had no problem on my Ubuntu but now that I have switched to OSX I have encountered this problem. I followed some of the solutions in the web but none helped.

```
monas-mbp:nlp mona$ git push origin master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Please let me know if more details should be revealed for help.

Comment: Well: Have you checked whether you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists? Also: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Comment: and how did you originally set up the repo on your mbp? "`git clone`" or "`git pull`"?  The error says "`publickey`".  Is your private key on your MacBook Pro somewhere (keychain or the id_rsa/id_dsa files)?

Comment: @PeeHaa Thanks for your help. it worked. Should I delete this post or would you please write that as an answer?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann There wasn't a need for that step but thanks for your offer of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a suitable dupe. I must say lack of sleep doesn't help my SO search fu at the moment so posting my comment as an answer.

The basic steps to solve it are:

1. generate ssh key on the server / machine
2. Add the key under your profile on github
3. ?
4. profit!

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys